# can't login at my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, login

Today, after I rebooted my server, I can't login at my server.
Everything works well.(like mysql or apache)
But I just can not login my server.

When I type any key(like `a' or '1') than console require the password. 
I can't type my ID at my server!

ssh works fine but I need to use my server directly for using gui.

Comment: And obviously it doesn't work if you just type the password when promet?

Comment: It just say "wrong ID and Password"

Comment: Try to install x server, a desktop enviroment  like xkce, etc and start it via ssh, then try to login form the graphic interface(usually tty7)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching to another TTY on the box? ALT+F1–F7

All else fails you can reset root pw (if that is your problem) by restarting into runlevel 0, single user mode, or whatever it is called in ubuntu. To do this you simply append `init 1` to your grub command before boot/init.

Comment: Nup. It dosen't work. I can login with ssh. And I can't switch any other tty. It dosen't work too.

Comment: The TTY thing could, but resetting the password is not going to be useful since the problem is that he can't login